# Can someone explain confusing unittest code?

Tags: python, unit-testing

this is the function for which is the unittest written for:

```
def swap_k(L, k):
    """ (list, int) -> NoneType

    Precondtion: 0 <= k <= len(L) // 2

    Swap the first k items of L with the last k items of L.

    >>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    >>> swap_k(nums, 2)
    >>> nums
    [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
    """
```

this is the unittest code:

```
def test_swap_k_list_length_6_swap_2(self):
    """Test swap_k with list of length 6 and number of items to swap 2.
    Also allow for the fact that there are potentially four alternate
    valid outcomes.
    """

    list_original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    list_outcome_1 = [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
    list_outcome_2 = [5, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1]
    list_outcome_3 = [6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2]
    list_outcome_4 = [6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1]
    valid_outcomes = [list_outcome_1, list_outcome_2, list_outcome_3, list_outcome_4]
    k = 2

    a1.swap_k(list_original,k)

    self.assertIn(list_original, valid_outcomes)
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

the unittest code passes and I don't understand why since I think the only valid outcome would be list_outcome_1 judging by the docstring of swap_k...

Comment: The unittest is more forgiving; it provides a whitelist of acceptable outcomes and the tested function provides *an* outcome that fits. *Why is this a problem?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the test can pass even if "valid_outcomes" contains *more* than what's valid. (In your opinion, list_outcome_1). It just means it sometimes won't *fail* when it should.

Second, I think the test is correct: the doc doesn't say that the first "k" items will be placed last in their original order, nor does it guarantee the same for the last "k" items. So any order of [1,2] could appear at the end of the list, and any order of [5,6] could appear at the beginning.

In general, if something is not guaranteed then I prefer not to assume it, even if it seems logical (a list is ordered, after all, so it's almost natural to assume that).

"Fixing" the unittest would also mean fixing the doc to guarantee order.

Comment: Thanks ! this explains it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.assertEqual(list_original, list_outcome_1)
```

and

```
self.assertIn(list_original, valid_outcomes)
```

both satisfies the test. Here you are testing whether the true outcome is in list of outcome which is true, so the test is valid.

However as per docstring

```
    self.assertEqual(list_original, list_outcome_1)
```

would have been better as it checks the equality.